# why is using if-else blocks inside views dreaded? - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What areas get affected by it?

code readability? maintainability? performance? security? any other?

my views have been using something like

```
if(Model.Showthis) {<div id = "showthis">...</div>} }
```

and does doing something like the following have security implications? --

```
<%if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && item.Poster.UserName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)%>
<%{%>
...
<%}%>
```

yes I read ["if" considered harmful in ASP.NET MVC View (.aspx) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042046/if-considered-harmful-in-asp-net-mvc-view-aspx-files) too, but it didn't exactly specify what areas get affected by it. I mean I wanted to make sure there are no security and performance implications, which the link didn't answer exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an issue with it as long as the branching logic is purely for UI concerns.  With that in mind I would change your second `if` to:

```
<%if (item.Poster.UserName == Model.CurrentUserName)%>
<%{%>
...
<%}%>
```

And set your model up so that the CurrentUserName property looks like this:

```
public string CurrentUserName
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
            : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Or even better if you're going to be checking author against current user a lot in your system, offload that property to a helper class that can be reused from multiple models.  Basically I wanted to get the implementation detail of what the current user's name is out of the view.

Comment: so if I just have to check whether the user is authenticated or not I should use String.IsEmptyOrNull(Model.UserNam) check?

Comment: If all you're caring about is if they're authenticated or not, you can just use `if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)`.  I thought you also needed to check if the post item was authored by the current user (ie: to display edit links or whatnot).

Answer (score 2):

I think the stigma persists from the transition from ASP to ASP.NET Forms.  MVC is a different beast.  With MVC3 and Razor it should help break the stigma and allow for more readable, easier to write Views.

That said, Domain and Business logic should never be in your template. But I see no problem, and frequently make use of conditional statements and loops to render UI in my Views.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with if else statements in your view template. What you want to avoid is business or model logic in side your view template. If the conditional is directly related to user interface, then it *belongs* in the view.

Yes, it can be a bit difficult to read because of the mix of HTML and C#, but so long as your view logic is in your view, and your model logic is in your model, you are properly maintaining separation of concerns.

With your second sample; it might make more sense to only have your Poster available to the View if the correct user is logged in in the first place; this seems like more of a Controller thing than a View thing to me.

A lot of people see if statements in the View and cringe, because it reminds them of classic ASP. But the problem with classic ASP was never that there was code and HTML in the same place; it was that there was business logic and presentation logic in the same place.

*Edit* Also, perhaps duplicate of ["if" considered harmful in ASP.NET MVC View (.aspx) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042046/if-considered-harmful-in-asp-net-mvc-view-aspx-files).

Comment: yes I read that link too, but it didn't exactly specify what areas get affected by it. I mean I wanted to make sure there are no security and performance implications, which the link didn't answer exactly

Answer (score 0):

**Why are they bad?**

As many people have already suggested it's because it *can* be a warning sign that business logic is leaking into your views which is a bad thing. Or that you are trying to do too much in your view. Often it's easier to setup the necessary data in your controller and just pass everything required (including any computed values) and have your view render it straight out. The flatter and simpler your view model is the better.

I don't think there is anything wrong with using if/else's for the true purpose of conditionally rendering UI. For example, if a user is logged in render this partial if they aren't than render something else.

I think a lot people get taken back and draw a hard and fast 'it's bad practice' because it can easily lead to *tag soup*. This phenomena has already been highlighted as a carry over from the asp.net webforms engine. Whilst still a good thing to be aware of, it is likely less of an issue with the razor engine as it's much cleaner and requires less syntax to achieve the same thing. The automatic switching in and out of C#/VB code to html and back is very simple with only an `@` required to re-enter a code block. I don't think this will create tag soup in the same way that angled brackets did <% %>. The amount of noise in the latter was what most people objected to (and rightly so).

Lastly, circumstances depending, if you find you are starting to get a lot of if/else logic in your view sometimes it is cleaner to put that into a HTML helper. I can't find the reference but I remember Rob Connery once saying that if you find yourself starting to write if statements in your view than it's a candidate for a html helper.

**Is there performance of security concerns?**

I don't think there is going to be any noticable performance differences or security concerns with what you are asking. But considering an authentication check like that is likely to be used in multiple views I would put it into a Html helper.

Answer (score 0):

If-else blocks are not bad specifically. Code in views is bad because you are mixing HTML markup with code. ASP.NET MVC is bad for separating static page design from dynamic UI code. Web Forms is better at separating static and programmatic UI elements.